# angularjs + angular-ui bootstrap = ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

Having got through https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial I've decided to add there some componenets from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . To do so I ran

bower install angular-bootstrap

as suggested here https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#installation. But I got

bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

Then I noticed that "angular-bootstrap" on bower (http://bower.io/search/?q=angular-bootstrap) points to some other project (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower) whereas https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap has name "angular-ui-bootstrap" there. So I tried

bower install angular-ui-bootstrap --save

and it seemed to work. So, the questions are:

1) Did I add correct angular-ui? Although bower worked, the components I added to my page were screwed.

2) Do I understand correctly that bower decides if version is suitable or not based on data it takes from its http://bower.io/?

Best regards, Eugene.

UPD: seems to be it was wrong angular-ui - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1936

Comment: Add this to your bower.cc "ignoredDependencies": ["angular"]